# How to remove special characters from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

When # comes in string, I want to split it on new line using JavaScript.

Please help me.

Sample input:

```
This application helps the user to instantiate #Removed#Basic#afdaf#Clip#Python#matching of many parts#
```

Expected output:

```
This helps the user to instantiate 
Removed
Basic
afdaf
Clip
Python
matching of many parts
```

Comment: have you tried for this by your own? then please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply `replace` `'#'` by `'\n'`

```js
var mainVar = 'This application helps the user to instantiate#Removed#Basic#afdaf#Clip#Python#matching';
console.log(mainVar.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '\n'));
```

Comment: Thanks  for your help. I used the logic which you have shared me and my code is working.

Comment: I have posted another question can you help me. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587578/display-sequence-when-result-comes

Answer (score 1):

Convert a string into array and loop through the array and print values one by one.

```js
var str = "helps the user to instantiate #Removed#Basic#afdaf#Clip#Python#matching of many parts#";

    str.split("#").forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
    });
```

Comment: I have dynamic output , how I can do it. every time str value change but it contains #. whatever code you have written is perfect but if I want to iterate then how I can do it.

Comment: Do you mean that you are getting this str value from an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

You should use the string replace function, with a single regex. Assuming by special characters

```js
var str = "This application helps the user to instantiate #Removed#Basic#afdaf#Clip#Python#matching of many parts#";
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "\n"));
```

Comment: This should not work if there is a number or any other special character other than '#' in the given string.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks for help . str value change every time so I have to use for loop to iterate over list . How I can do it.

Comment: I have to implement your code in below function. could you help me.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution will split based on the # and store it in an array.
This solution will come in handy with splitting strings.

```
var sentence = '#Removed#Basic#afdaf#Clip#Python#matching of many parts#'

var newSentence = [];
for(var char of sentence.split("#")){
    console.log(char); // This will print each string on a new line
    newSentence.push(char);
}
console.log(newSentence.join(" "));
```