# Display sequence when result comes

Tags: javascript

I am working on chatbot and it is worrking fine. If multiple matching result found then it displays multiple result as below. I want to formatting it properly, I want to display numbers before results . How I can do it using javascript.

```
function createRowMultiresult(jobjects) {
    var $div = $('<div class="chat Bot"></div>');
    var $div2 = $('<div class="user-photo"><img src="{% static 
                "Robot.jpg"%}" /></div>');
    $div.append($div2);
    var $tbl = $('<table style="width:100%;"></table>');

    if (jobjects.length>1){
    var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">Multiple results Found for 
              your query. Please search with specific keyword</td></tr>');
    $tbl.append($tr);
    }

    for(var x=0; x<jobjects.length;x++){
        var currentobj = jobjects[x];

        if (currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") != -1){
            var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="https:GUIDES' 
                      + currentobj.ans +'" target="_blank" >Click Here for 
                      Download</a></td></tr>');
                $tbl.append($tr);
        }
        else{
            var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">' + 
                      currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>") +'</td> 
                      </tr>');
            $tbl.append($tr);

            if (currentobj.Pic.length>7){
                var $tr = $("<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><img 
                          class='productpic' src='{% static '/Pictures/' %}" 
                          + currentobj.Pic +"' /></td></tr>");
                $tbl.append($tr);
            }
        }
    }

    var $par = $('<p class="chat-message"></p>');
    $par.append($tbl);
    $div.append($par);
    $chatlog.append($div);

 }

Actual output:
Multiple result found-
car-finance loan1
car-finance loan2
car-finance loan3
car-finance loan4 

Expected output-
1.car-finance loan1
2.car-finance loan2
3.car-finance loan3
4.car-finance loan4
```

Comment: Do you want to Order By some value? If not, then simply initilize a variable by 1 and increase it by every element, print that element before each result.

Comment: Actually I want to do formatting ..now my results are coming but their is no formatting. I want to display 1,2,3,4..so on before each result. As I have written in Expected output area.

Comment: your increment variable should do the numbering.

Comment: Sure, from above code I failed to get your formatting block, please post only the formation block

Comment: I have formatted code..please refer and let me know.

Comment: I have posted the code below, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes,

```
function createRowMultiresult(jobjects) {
var $div = $('<div class="chat Bot"></div>');
var $div2 = $('<div class="user-photo"><img src="{% static 
            "Robot.jpg"%}" /></div>');
$div.append($div2);
var $tbl = $('<table style="width:100%;"></table>');

if (jobjects.length>1){
var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">Multiple results Found for 
          your query. Please search with specific keyword</td></tr>');
$tbl.append($tr);
}

for(var x=0; x<jobjects.length;x++){
    var currentobj = jobjects[x];

    if (currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") != -1){
        var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="https:GUIDES' 
                  + currentobj.ans +'" target="_blank" >Click Here for 
                  Download</a></td></tr>');
            $tbl.append($tr);
    }
    else{
        var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">' +(x+1)+'.'+ 
                  currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>") +'</td> 
                  </tr>');
        $tbl.append($tr);

        if (currentobj.Pic.length>7){
            var $tr = $("<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><img 
                      class='productpic' src='{% static '/Pictures/' %}" 
                      + currentobj.Pic +"' /></td></tr>");
            $tbl.append($tr);
        }
    }
}

var $par = $('<p class="chat-message"></p>');
$par.append($tbl);
$div.append($par);
$chatlog.append($div);
```

}

Comment: I have one more question related to javascript..I want to write else condition in above code..first if statement contains "Guide" related data , else contains "information" releted data , and I want third else in which I want to display "indexing " related data. How I can do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588953/bind-output-variable-to-javascript-for-displaying-result

Comment: could you help me to solve this problem-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588953/bind-output-variable-to-javascript-for-displaying-result

Comment: could you help me to solve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590999/how-to-connect-python-output-to-javascript-for-displaying-result

Comment: if(condition){.....}; else if(condition) {....}; else {......}; this is the syntax for multi condition if-else if block.

Comment: I answer your other question on that page, check please.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the numbering from `for(var x=0; x<jobjects.length;x++){`
Just add the x value where ever you need the ordering number.
Like below

```
function createRowMultiresult(jobjects) {

  var $div = $('<div class="chat Bot"></div>');
  var $div2 = $('<div class="user-photo"><img src="{% static 
    "Robot.jpg" %
  }
  " /></div>');
  $div.append($div2);
  var $tbl = $('<table style="width:100%;"></table>');
  if (jobjects.length > 1) {
    var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">Multiple results Found 
      for your query.Please search with specific keyword < /td></tr > ');
      $tbl.append($tr);
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < jobjects.length; x++) {
      var currentobj = jobjects[x];
      if (currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") != -1) {
        var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="https:' +
          currentobj.ans + '" target="_blank" >Click Here</a>  <
          /td></tr > ');
          $tbl.append($tr);
        }
        else {
          var $tr = $('<tr><td 
            style = "padding:5px;" > 'x + ' ' + currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>")  +
            '</td></tr>');
          $tbl.append($tr);
          if (currentobj.Pic.length > 7) {
            var $tr = $("<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><img class='productpic' 
              src = '{% static ' / Pictures / ' %}" + currentobj.Pic +"' / > < /td></tr > ");
              $tbl.append($tr);
            }
          }
        }
        var $par = $('<p class="chat-message"></p>');
        $par.append($tbl);
        $div.append($par);
        $chatlog.append($div);
      }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I need ordering in " if (jobjects.length > 1) {
    var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">Multiple results Found 
      for your query.Please search with specific keyword < /td></tr > ');
      $tbl.append($tr);
    }"

Comment: This code is not working..when I used x value then chatbot is stopped.

Comment: I think mistake is in apostrophe... var $tr = $('<tr><td 
 style = "padding:5px;" > 'x + ' ' + currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>")  +
 '</td></tr>');

Comment: ahh, missed a +
`var $tr = $('<tr><td 
            style = "padding:5px;" > ' + (x + 1) + ' ' + currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>")  +
            '</td></tr>');`

Comment: can you solve this problem-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588953/bind-output-variable-to-javascript-for-displaying-result..code is same as above, I only have to change else to elseif and create new else , in which I have to bind indexing related code.

Comment: could you help me to solve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590999/how-to-connect-python-output-to-javascript-for-displaying-result

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, and you just need little bit of modification need to change

```
for(var x=0; x<jobjects.length;x++) {
    var currentobj = jobjects[x];
    if (currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") != -1){
        var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="https:' + 
        currentobj.ans +'" target="_blank" >Click Here</a> 
        </td></tr>');
        $tbl.append($tr);
    }
    else {
        var $tr = $('<tr><td 
        style="padding:5px;">'currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>") 
        +'</td></tr>');
        $tbl.append($tr);
        if (currentobj.Pic.length>7){
            var $tr = $("<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><img class='productpic' 
            src='{% static '/Pictures/' %}" + currentobj.Pic +"' /></td></tr>");
            $tbl.append($tr);
        }
    }
}
```

the above code needs to be updated with the below code

```
for(var x=0; x<jobjects.length;x++){
    var currentobj = jobjects[x];
    if (currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") != -1){
        var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="https:' + 
        currentobj.ans +'" target="_blank" >Click Here</a> 
        </td></tr>');
        $tbl.append($tr);
    }
    else {
        var $tr = $('<tr><td 
        style="padding:5px;">'Number(x + 1)' + ' ' +'currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>") 
        +'</td></tr>');
        $tbl.append($tr);
        if (currentobj.Pic.length>7){
            var $tr = $("<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><img class='productpic' 
            src='{% static '/Pictures/' %}" + currentobj.Pic +"' /></td></tr>");
            $tbl.append($tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only changed - 'Number(x + 1)' Right, when I use this in my script then chatbot is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588953/bind-output-variable-to-javascript-for-displaying-result

Comment: could you help me to solve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590999/how-to-connect-python-output-to-javascript-for-displaying-result