# How to display output in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using python for backend and javascript for user interface, I have multiple files stored in folder and I want to display that using javascript.

```
function createRowMultiresult(jobjects) {
   var $div = $('<div class="chat Bot"></div>');
   var $div2 = $('<div class="user-photo"><img src="{% static "Robot.jpg%}" /></div>');
   $div.append($div2);
   var $tbl = $('<table style="width:100%;"></table>');

   if (jobjects.length>1){
     var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">Multiple results Found for 
                 your query. Please search with specific keyword</td> 
                 </tr>');
      $tbl.append($tr);
   }
   for(var x=0; x<jobjects.length;x++){
      var currentobj = jobjects[x];
   if (currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") != -1){
      var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"><a href="https://Guide' + 
                currentobj.ans +'" target="_blank" >Click Here 
                Guide</a></td></tr>');
      $tbl.append($tr);
   }
   else if(currentobj.ans.indexOf("/AV") == -1){
      var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">' +(x+1)+'.'+ 
                   currentobj.ans.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "<br/>") +'</td> 
                   </tr>');
      $tbl.append($tr);

      if (currentobj.Pic.length>7){
        var $tr = $("<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><img 
                      class='productpic' src='{% static '/Pictures/' %}" + currentobj.Pic +"' /></td></tr>");
      $tbl.append($tr);
      }
   else{

   }

  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hey Pitto, I am begineer in javascript .Above script works well.  I need your help to write logic in else condition.

Comment: else {var $tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:5px;">Bot: D'OH!!</td> 
                 </tr>');
      $tbl.append($tr);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the conditionng a bit more different. `if(condition.indexOf("Guide")>-1)
{ // do something for Guide Related Data } 
else if(condition.indexOf("information")>-1){// do something for information Related Data}
else if(condition.indexOf("indexing")>-1){// do something for indexing Related Data}
else{// no condition met, so do whatever requires here}`
 Your above code fails cause you check if 'AV" exists or not, in first two checks. if "AV" doesnt exist, it makes 1st else if true, and the condition met there. So that is the problem of your code.

Comment: Its my pleasure